Gradle ClassNotFoundException for org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
I'm trying to execute my Android App and every time I see this message. I already tried to reinstall Gradle, Java and Node. But nothing changed.
    Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
    error Failed to install the app. Command failed with exit code 1: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
    Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.
    info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

I tried to reinstall Java, Gradle, Node, add new things to my path, but it didn't worked.

Your error message contains the following: Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details. Did you try doing that? By the way, have you read [ask]?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
